# circular colorTransform

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, alpha, bitmapdata, colortransform

Is there a way to apply a colorTransform to a BitmapData in a circle rather than in a rectangle?

Instead of erasing rectangular parts of an image by reducing the alpha channel as in the code below, I'd like to do it in circles.

```
 _bitmap.colorTransform(new Rectangle(mouseX-d/2, mouseY-d/2, d, d),
 new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, .5, 0, 0, 0, 1));
```

I do have some code which loops through the pixels, extracts the alpha value and uses setPixel but it seams significantly slower than the colorTransform function.

Comment: by setPixel you're using BitmapData right?

Comment: yes, also you need to use setPixel32 when working with the alpha channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a circle using the drawing API (flash.display.Graphics) and then drawing that onto the bitmap data with BlendMode.ERASE. That might solve your problem, if I understand it correctly.

```
var circle : Shape = new Shape;
circle.graphics.beginFill(0xffcc00, 1);
circle.graphics.drawEllipse(-50, -50, 100, 100);

// Create a transformation matrix for the draw() operation, with
// a translation matching the mouse position.
var mtx : Matrix = new Matrix();
mtx.translate(mouseX, mouseY);

// Draw circle at mouse position with the ERASE blend mode, to
// set affected pixels to alpha=0.
myBitmap.draw(circle, mtx, null, BlendMode.ERASE);
```

I'm not 100% sure that the ERASE blend mode works satisfyingly with the draw() command, but I can't see why it shouldn't. Please let me know how it works out!

Comment: Works a charm ! The only change I made was to set the fill of the circle to alpha .5 or less to achieve the same affect as the colorTransform I used. That is to erase the image more slowly. Many thanks.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the 3rd, ColorTransform parameter to the draw method _bitmap.draw(circle, mtx, new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, .5), 0, 0, 0, 1), BlendMode.ERASE)

Comment: I'm glad! With regards to using a ColorTransform just to decrease the alpha, my gut feeling tells me that it can't possible perform as well as simply having a < 1 alpha on the circle fill. Simply because the ColorTransform will be applied (and in your sample code, instantiated) each time you draw, which means one extra operation.

Comment: It might not perform as well but it looks slightly better in that you don't get the circle edges showing up as much. Thanks again for your help.